# refresh datatable when close dialog without need to click on a button jsf2 primefaces

Tags: javascript, dialog, datatable, primefaces, refresh

I have this dialog :

```
<p:dialog  header="Commande editée le #{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande.dateMaj} par l'#{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande.utilisateur.type} #{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande.utilisateur.nom} #{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande.utilisateur.prenom}" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" id="carDlg"  
                     update="cars" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">
```

it is displayed when the user click on the button belowint the datatable :

```
<p:column style="width:40px">                         
                        <p:commandButton  id="selectButton" action="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}" update=":form:carDlg" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="plus de détails">  
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande}" />  
                        </p:commandButton>                       
                    </p:column>
```

I want when the user close tis dialog, the method below will be executed :

```
public String refresh(){
    this.selectedMajCommande.setLu(true);
    System.out.println("je suis la alors : "+this.selectedMajCommande.isLu());
    hch.updateCommandeMaj(selectedMajCommande);
    return "acceuil";
}
```

it allow to refresh data into the datatable, I succeded to make this with a button in the dialog like this :

```
 <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="fermer" update="cars" oncomplete="carDialog.hide()"
                                     action="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}" />
```

but I want to do this only when close the dialog,without the need for this button in the box

here is the datatable that I want to refresh :

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{acceuilUserController.lc_maj}"  tableStyle="width:auto" rowStyleClass="#{(car.lu == false) ? 'red' : null}" >  

                    <p:column headerText="Commande N° : " style="width:100px">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.commande.id}" />  
                    </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Date de mise à jour : " style="width:100px">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.dateMaj}" />  
                    </p:column> 

                    <p:column headerText="Decision : " style="width:100px">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.decison}" />  
                    </p:column> 

                    <p:column headerText="Etat : " style="width:100px">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.etat}" />  
                    </p:column> 

                    <p:column style="width:40px">                         
                        <p:commandButton  id="selectButton" action="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}" update=":form:carDlg" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="plus de détails">  
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{acceuilUserController.selectedMajCommande}" />  
                        </p:commandButton>                       
                    </p:column> 

                </p:dataTable>
```

how can achieve this, thank you in advance

Comment: `p:dialog` doesn't have the `update` attribute. Apart from that, the PrimeFaces way to update a component is to use `p:ajax` inside the form that triggers the change in the data on the server side. Please show us that component.

Comment: Now you have added some columns that are not relevant to the question. We need to understand what event triggers the change in the data. Otherwise, what's the reason for refreshing?

Comment: Not a complete solution but you could add a f:ajax click event to a close command button in the dialog: <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="cars" listener="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}"/> and change acceuilUserController.refresh(ActionEvent event).

Comment: I do all that you say me by adding this line : <f:ajax event="close" execute="@this" render="cars" listener="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}"/> (because event='click' doesn't be supported) into my '<p:dialog> but it generated me this error : listener="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}": Method refresh not found
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /vues_utilisateur/acceuil.xhtml @51,124 listener="#{acceuilUserController.refresh()}": Method refresh not found

Comment: sorry, it works, te problem was that I had the managedBean in RequestScope but now I make it with ViewScoped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do using jQuery to bind a click event in such a way that it invokes a click event of a PrimeFaces commandButton component that is already configured to partially process and update components of your choosing.  I did something similar by putting this script in a composite component that I placed outside all of my dialogs, but of course there are many ways to do this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Searching for naming container that contains my dialog...
    var dashboardPanel = jQuery('*[id*=#{cc.attrs.id}]');
    // Find the dialog closer button by its unique class
    var closerButton = dashboardPanel.children().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
    closerButtons.bind('click', function(event) {
        // Use set timeout to delay the event if you want to see close animation effect
        setTimeout(function() { //Some logic to find the button client id
            var menuItemId = 'view#{cc.attrs.id}'.replace('Panel', '');
            jQuery('#' + menuItemId).click();
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Of course if you do not have a commandButton with a dynamic id or it is not in a repeating container then it will be far simpler to refer to it directly in Javascript by its `widgetVar`.

```
commandButtonWidget.jq.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update `RequestContext` like this:

```
public void update() {
   RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
   requestContext.update("form:cars");
}
```